# completely remove mariadb database and root password

Tags: mysql, mariadb

The system is Fedora 32. Mariadb was installed and operational; it is now necessary to reinitialize Mariadb and all data and users.

I removed mariadb-server and mariadb and erased /etc/my.cnf and my.cnf.d. I then reinstalled mariadb and mariadb-server and ran the mysql_secure_installation script. It found the original root password but otherwise completed normally.

I then logged into mariadb. I expected to find the users from the original installation had been removed; however they had not.

show databases; shows the original tables. They were not removed.

select * from mysql.user; showed the original users.

How can mariadb be completely removed including all users, data, and passwords?

Answer (score 1):

You need to delete the data in your datadir, since that is where this is stored. The default location is `/var/lib/mysql/`. Shut down MariaDB and delete everything inside the datadir without deleting the datadir itself (as you want to avoid having to recreate the directory with exactly the right permissions):

```
sudo systemctl stop mariadb
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/mysql/*
```

Then use [mysql_install_db](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mysql_install_db/) to re-initialise the datadir.

Comment: Thank you. That worked through to 'systemcth start mariadb.service'. It errored with:  Process: 1390711 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Comment: Second update: Somehow in that process the directory /var/lib/mysql ended up being owned by root. Changing it to mysql allowed mariadb to initialize.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the user,host from `select user,host` from mysql.user;

```
DROP USER '{user}'@'{host}'
```

If there are non-system database (exclude 'mysql', 'information_schema' and 'performance_schema'), in `SHOW DATABASES` they can be removed with `DROP DATABASE'